# Vimrc not updating

Tags: git, vim

I am trying to setup vim to wrap my git commits to 72 characters but I am having trouble doing so. When I edit ":e $myvimrc" and add the settings to wrap the text it doesn't seem to work. I tried to open the vimrc file directly form my program files to check that the changes I have made had indeed been saved, but they are not showing in the file.

Strange thing is that when I open the vimrc file in vim to edit it the changes I made are still there, they just don't seem to be saving to the actual file.

I have tried to edit the vimrc directly as well but it wont allow me to save in that location. Hopefully im just doing something silly and if I am I apologies, very fresh to git and vim. Thanks in advance

Comment: show what have you done in your vimrc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended to place your personal Vim configuration in your user's home directory (on Windows, typically `C:\Users\<yourname>`; or use `:e $HOME/_vimrc` inside Vim).

If your `~/.vimrc` file currently resides in Vim's installation directory, under `C:\Program Files` (i.e. `$VIM/_vimrc`), then you're experiencing the effects of the Windows [File System Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), redirecting non-admin writes to Program Files into a virtual store (cp. [UAC Virtualization and how it affects your Installers](https://decibel.ni.com/content/groups/windows-7/blog/2009/10/02/uac-virtualization-and-how-it-affects-your-installers).

Comment: Hi Ingo, thanks for the reply. Based on your comment I have looked for it in my  virtual store location and have found it in C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\Vim, Thank you so much for your assistance. It has been updating to this location so it must be my vim settings are incorrect, I will look into them now. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

usually you don't need do special setting for gitcommit Filetype. Because GITCOMMIT was pre-defined as `wrap & textwidth=72` under your `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/gitcommit.vim`

Check if you have `filetype on` in your vimrc, so that the filetype plugins are activated.

Comment: Hi Kent, I have located my gitcommit.vim and the file specifies "setlocal nomodeline tabstop=8 formatoptions+=tl textwidth=72"

Comment: I have mad sure the filtype on line was in my vimrc file but still no joy. I have been looking into other possible solutions but no joy just yet.